# I want to convert my HTML page into image and upload the same on server using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

I'm using html2canvas ,able to generate the screenshot and open the same in another window. However, the response of my HTML page is dynamically created and I need to upload the same screenshot to server, Bluemix recursively and retrieve the same from any other application using the URI.

```js
html2canvas(document.getElementById("mydiv")).then(function(canvas) {
     // Export the canvas to its data URI representation
      var base64image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
     // Open the image in a new window
    window.open(base64image , "_blank");
  });
```

I have tried saving the image using Blob, but that's not working.

```js
html2canvas(document.getElementById("mydiv")).then(function(canvas) {
    // Export canvas as a blob 
    canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
        // Generate file download
        window.saveAs(blob, "yourwebsite_screenshot.png");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't get real HTML rendering to  per se currently, because canvas context does not have functions to render HTML elements.

There are some emulations:

html2canvas project http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/index.html (basically a HTML renderer attempt built on Javascript + canvas)

HTML to SVG to  might be possible depending on your use case:

https://github.com/miohtama/Krusovice/blob/master/src/tools/html2svg2canvas.js

Also if you are using Firefox you can hack some extended permissions and then render a DOM window to

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas#Rendering_Web_Content_Into_A_Canvas